# How to save the compiled JasperReport as a .jasper in a file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have this code. I have a jrxml file. I can create a jasperReport object successfully. But I don't know how to create jasper file from this and I want to save jasper to a file location in c drive.

```
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
JasperCompileManager.compileReport(getResourceAsStream("Sample_Report.jrxml"));
    try {
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                .compileReport("C:\\xxx.jrxml");
        System.out.println("jasper created " + jasperReport);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Method you want to use is

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\xxx.jrxml", "C:\\xxx.jasper");
```

Answer (score 0):

After `JasperCompileManager.compileReport` you can call `JRSaver.saveObject`

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSaver;
...
jrep= JasperCompileManager.compileReport(srcJrxmlFileName);
JRSaver.saveObject(jrep, destJasperFileName);
```